# Grid view paging -ASP.net mvc and linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm using nop commercer2.6
So I want to crate custom report and I want to do paging for that report.

This is my function

```
 public virtual IPagedList<HireItemReportLine> HireItemReport(int ceremony_id, string Fname, string Mname, string Lnmae, string emailAdd, int sesson_id, int pageIndex, int pageSize)
        {

            var query1 = from opv in _opvRepository.Table
                         join o in _orderRepository.Table on opv.OrderId equals o.Id
                         join gr in _graduandRepository.Table on opv.graduand_id equals gr.Id
                         join pv in _productVariantRepository.Table on opv.ProductVariantId equals pv.Id
                         join p in _productRepository.Table on pv.ProductId equals p.Id
                         join c in _ceremonyRepository.Table on gr.ceremony_id equals c.Id
                         join s in _seasonRepository.Table on c.season_id equals s.Id
                         where (!o.Deleted) && (opv.IsHireItem == true) &&
                         (!p.Deleted) &&
                         (!pv.Deleted)
                         select new
                         {
                             opvTable = opv,
                             grTable = gr,
                             seaTable = s,

                         };

            if (!(sesson_id == 0))
                query1 = query1.Where(item => item.seaTable.Id == sesson_id);

             if (!(ceremony_id == 0))                 
                 query1 = query1.Where(item => item.opvTable.ceremony_id == ceremony_id);

             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Fname))
                 query1 = query1.Where(item => item.grTable.first_name == Fname);

             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Mname))
                 query1 = query1.Where(item => item.grTable.middle_name == Mname);

             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Lnmae))
                 query1 = query1.Where(item => item.grTable.last_name == Lnmae);

             if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(emailAdd))
                 query1 = query1.Where(item => item.grTable.email == emailAdd);


             var query2 = from opv in query1
                          group opv by opv.opvTable.OrderId into g
                          select new
                          {
                              OrderId = g.Key,
                              TotalAmount = g.Sum(x => x.opvTable.PriceInclTax),


                          };
 int totalCount = query2.Count();
             query2 = query2.OrderByDescending(x => x.OrderId);

             var result = query2.ToList().Select(x =>
            {
                return new HireItemReportLine()
                {
                    OrderId = x.OrderId,                   
                    Amount= x.TotalAmount,

                };
            });

             var orders_1 = result.ToList();       


             return new PagedList<HireItemReportLine>(orders_1, pageIndex, pageSize,totalCount);
        }
```

This is PagedLis() function

```
 public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        TotalCount = totalCount;
        TotalPages = TotalCount / pageSize;

        if (TotalCount % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        this.PageSize = pageSize;
        this.PageIndex = pageIndex;
        this.AddRange(source);

    }
```

I want to bind this data to grid view and it has paging. I can bind and it shows page numbers.but my My problem is when I click page no's in grid view it always show only first page. 
Do you have any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think these paging/sorting/grouping would get easier while using third party tools. However, please check the below link for paging/sorting in c# using LINQ.

[Custom Paging](http://mvc.syncfusion.com/demos/ui/grid/DataBinding/CustomBinding)